# Android two dimensional list view

Tags: android, listview

I have are requirement in my current application to create a giant matrix of cells. Say maybe a maximum of 50 rows and 50 columns. Each cell is about the width of the screen. This creates a problem because building a single view of that size is not feasible. This seems to lend itself well to having a listview that shows the cells lazily but one that allows columns and rows instead of just rows. Does anyone know if something like this exists?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at GridView, visit [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) for official documentation and guidelines from android developers' official blog.

Comment: That gives me the layout that I'm after but it doesn't scroll horizontally.

Comment: Enclose it in a horizontally scrollable ScrollView and you should be good to go.

Comment: This causes problems as per this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361958/horizontalscrollview-shrinks-gridview-to-small-line

Answer (score 0):

Take GridView with 2 columns and define custom adapter for the same.

Just check this Answer for more information: [Android - Multi Columns ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710642/android-multi-columns-listview/7721688#7721688)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out that this seems impossible using a grid view. It seems that grid views are not at all designed to scroll both vertically and horizontally. In the end I made a completely custom control that works in a similar way but allows both horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Comment: Ah, I am in a similar situation.  How did you go about solving the problem?  Any chance of source, or at least interesting snippets to your custom widget?